# How to use preg_match to extract a version number and date from a string?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this string:

```
= 1.0.2 - 2021-01-18 =
```

I am looking to use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the version number and the date from it and put it into an array, I have the following code but I'm definitely doing something wrong here:

```
preg_match('/^([\d.]+)[\- ](\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d) =/', $string, $match)
```

I'm unsure how to deal with the = in the string and the hyphen in the middle or even if the above will successfully match a 3 digit version number and date.

I am expecting $match to contain an array of the version number and date.

How can I use preg_match to get this data in an array from the string?

Comment: Please provide 3 to 5 different input strings to reveal how your data may vary.  Then provide your exact desired output from each input.  We can't see where your current code is failing (outside of the fact that you aren't accommodating the leading `= `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not variable, just match what you want in the pattern.  This assumes version could be `10.1.204` etc. and the date will always be `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
preg_match('/= (\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) =/', $string, $match);
```

Or some minor corrections to yours:

```
/= ([\d.]+)[\s-]+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d) =/
```

Or:

```
/^= ([\d.]+)[\s-]+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d) =/
```

Then look in `$match[1]` and `$match[2]`.  However, the `trim` and `explode` answer is probably better.

Comment: ...or even `/([\d.]+)[\s-]+([\d-]+)` if we aren't doing any kind of validation (purely extracting a strictly formatted string.  I wish there was more sample data so that we could see the variability of the incoming text.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use **preg_match** at all. This is simpler (and faster) if you just use some basic string manipulation:

```
$s = '= 1.0.2 - 2021-01-18 =';
$s = trim($s, '= ');
$ss = explode(' - ', $s);
```

Now **$ss[0]** is the version and **$ss[1]** is the date.